# Rails, JWT : Why is current_user called/executed as frequent as the times it is stated in the erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

application_conroller.rb

```
def current_user
    p 'current_user'
    user = decode_jwt(cookies.permanent[:jwt_token]
    @current_user ||= user
end
```

then, I have some.html.erb

```
<%=current_user.id%>
<%=current_user.first_name %>
<%=current_user.last_name %>
```

Then, my log prints out

```
"current_user"
"current_user"
"current_user"
```

It seems whenever I call current_user inside the html, then it literally goes through what is stated inside current_user.

I start to experience this by switching from conventional rails approach to JWT. Definitely this situation ends up slowing down the request. What would be the good practice to avoid unnecessary current_user execution?

Answer (score 0):

When you say `<%= current_user.id %>` in your view, you're calling the `current_user` method and then calling the `id` method on what is returned. Then you say `<%= current_user.first_name %>` which calls `current_user` (again) and then called `first_name` on what is returned. And so on. There's nothing that will automatically recognize that you're calling the same method to get the same return value and then optimize it all away.

You're attempting to memoize `current_user` (a common thing) at the end of your method:

```
@current_user ||= user
```

but that doesn't help because, presumably, all the work is in `decode_jwt(cookies.permanent[:jwt_token])` and you do that every time regardless of what `@current_user` is.

The memoization would normally look more like:

```
@current_user ||= decode_jwt(cookies.permanent[:jwt_token])
```

so that you only recode the JWT once (i.e. when `@current_user.nil?`) and then reuse it thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

```
def current_user
  p 'current_user'
  user = decode_jwt(cookies.permanent[:jwt_token]
  @current_user ||= user
end
```

This is a method. When you type `current_user` it's calling the method and executing it. If you want to output a variable, use the one you're making `@current_user`, or set a new variable in the controller: `@user = current_user` and change your view to be:

```
<%=@user.id%>
<%=@user.first_name %>
<%=@user.last_name %>
```

> I start to experience this by switching from conventional rails
>   approach to JWT. Definitely this situation ends up slowing down the
>   request.

By their nature JWT feel like they make more authentication requests because each request requires checking the token in your code. But in reality, sessions are doing pretty much the same work and they require storing data server-side whereas JWT store them client-side. Plus, if your `decode_jwt` function is slowing down your server significantly due to three extra calls, you might want to review it.

Comment: You **definitely** want `@current_user ||= decode_jwt(cookies.permanent[:jwt_token])` instead of having those two on separate lines. That prevents decode_jwt from being called everytime you hit the method.